# Submitting a paid iPhone application to the app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am about to submit an iPhone application to the app store I want to sell it in Tier 1 matrix which is 0.99 US$, I am not going to offer any upgrades or buying any extra content inside my application.

In my case do I need to use In App Purchase?

I have read this tutorial [In App Purchases: A Full Walkthrough](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) but I am not sure if i must implement Store Kit framework in my app.

Comment: @Dan @Deeps @rckoenes:
Thank you all your answer's were correct, just wanna say something All Hail Google Android because Apple is not making programming easy to anyone with thier strict policies

Comment: I marking @rckoenes answer's the correct answer bedause he was the first one that is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No "In App purchase" is what for have extra content that you can buy from with in your app, just like the name says.

If you are just going to sell your app there is no need for "In App purchase", just set the price to Tier 1 and you app will be sold voor $0.99

Comment: My app requires a paid subscription to be able to access it, that also does not need IAP?

Comment: Yes, then you will need to include a complete In App purchase functionality, with subscription type a the In app purchase type.

Comment: Thank you very much then any app that requires a paid subscription need to use IAP? I just wanna be clear.

Comment: Yes, Apple wants you to offer the subscription as an Iap in your app.

Answer (score 1):

No. Store Kit framework is for in App Purchases which you don't want.

Comment: My app requires a paid subscription to be able to access it, that also does not need IAP?

Comment: @Samssom - Then yes you need the IAP framework using Subscription as the type of IAP.

Answer (score 1):

No, You don't want to bother about In-app purchases if you don't have any extra content to download/activate. Just set your app price $.99 (tier1) and submit binary files and you are ready to go. Don't even think about In-app purchase.

Comment: My app requires a paid subscription to be able to access it, that also does not need IAP?

Comment: YES, Then you must need IAP integration and type would be subscription. In this scenario you need to submit your app as Free and They need to subscribe in order to access content of the app. But I don't think Apple allowed to do that. You should have something to access to user. You can not put all stuffs which require subscription. Let me know.